# ACS712 connected to Raspberry Pi through MCP3008

Tags: sensor, analog-to-digital

Is it possible to bind the [ACS712](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/0712.pdf) sensor in the following way?

- 5V to 5V Raspberry Pi pin
- GND to GND pin
- Out pin to a [MCP3008](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf) channel

The MCP3008 is an analogue to digital converter.

I'm asking this because I looked over [an instructables tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Measure-AC-Current-using-Hall-Effect-Sensor/?ALLSTEPS) and I would like to make it simpler.

Comment: I suspect that the op amp is necessary to get the right amount of current from the sensor to the board. You could estimate that from spec sheets. Keep in mind that the MCP3008 will have requirements separate from the Pi's, so you need to include that and it might require further tinkering with the op amp configuration. I like the Pi, but it's not quite as nice for analog as the Arduino shown in the Instructable since the Arduino has on-board ADC.

Answer (score 1):

there are lot of breakout boards which come with ACS712 sensor and ADC.
and the ADC comes with I2C interface so you can connect directly to your pi.
this video shows the entire process.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5TtlNWLuc8

Comment: For others information, YouTube video is taken down.